# getAllEntriesByKey causes error: Unknown or unsupported object type in Vector

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes

I get the following error in a xp:messages control:

> Error in lotus.domino.local.View, line -2: NotesException: Unknown or
>   unsupported object type in Vector

It is generated in the following code in my Java class:

```
View vw = db.getView(viewName);
if(null != vw){ 
ViewEntryCollection vec
-> vec = vw.getAllEntriesByKey(key);
}
```

key is here a provided String.

Anyone has an explanation for this?

Comment: Do you actually have the `->` in your code?

Comment: You contradict yourself with "key is here a provided String", the error message states "Unknown or unsupported object type in Vector", so tell us, what's in the key variable exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check that your variable `key` is not null? I get this error message if I provide a key parameter that is null.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in a String, not a Vector. You need to create a Vector, then add your string as the first element to it, same as in SSJS.

```
Vector vec = new Vector();
vec.add(key)
vw.getAllEntriesByKey(vec);
```

This is one of the reasons that ODA's method signature is `getAllEntriesByKey(Object key)`, so our abstraction layer does all that for you. Plus once you get the result, you can use standard Java looping to process the loop (`for (ViewEntry ent : vec) {....}`)

Comment: You don't need to create a Vector: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_GETALLENTRIESBYKEY_METHOD_JAVA.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to consider. The first is your syntax. The code should be as follows

```
View vw = db.getView(viewName);
if(null != vw){ 
    ViewEntryCollection vec = vw.getAllEntriesByKey(key);
    // do something with the vec
}
```

The second is the exception message:

Unknown or unsupported object type in vector.

The documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_GETALLENTRIESBYKEY_METHOD_JAVA.html) has the method signatures. The `key` variable you've mentioned is a String so the method should be the one you've used:

```
public ViewEntryCollection getAllEntriesByKey(Object key) throws NotesException
```

When you remove the -> from the code does it work as expected?